# Safari Extension - Opening a hidden Tab

Tags: safari, safari-extension

The Safari extension docs mentioned that it is possible to create a hidden browser tab: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1

```
browserWindow.openTab()—creates a new tab at any point in the array. The tab can be hidden.
```

However, there was no further mentioned on how it can be achieved.

Comment: I think by "hidden" they mean "opened in the background"—that is, without getting focus. This is done with `browserWindow.openTab("background")`. See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserWindowClassReference/SafariBrowserWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009794).

Comment: @canisbos thanks for your comment, so that means it is not possible to open a hidden tab.
So what is a good place for background loading of a given URL ?
I can not do that via the injected script ajax call due to cross domain restriction.

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest in the global page, a popover, or an extension bar. If necessary, use message passing to pass the downloaded HTML to an injected script.